# app doesn't open and always redirect to app store from the deep link if it is already installed in ios

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io, deeplink

I'm using `Branch.io` `with deep links`. if someone has installed the app or not, the `link` open the **app store**.

if the app is **already installed**, it shows `Open` button and it open the app and work properly.

if the app **isn't installed** , it shows 'Install' button and , when installed and open, then work properly.

what I want is, if the app already installed, when user tap on deep link, it should open the app and if not, should goes to appstore for installation.

> Is it possible to open the app with `deeplink` in `branch io`, if it has already installed or it above one is the normal procedure. hope your help with this.

Comment: I am a bit confused, because what you _want_ to happen seems to be the same as what is _actually_ happening already. Could you clarify?

Comment: did you configure your app to handle `universal link`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue too. Here is what went wrong, "When an app is opened via a Universal Link, tapping on the "app.link" button in the upper right-hand corner of the screen, as shown in the screenshot below, will disable Universal Links for the app." 
solution: -> Copy the link in notes -> Long press -> UIActionSheet pops up - click on "Open in " https://support.branch.io/support/solutions/articles/6000153326-ios-universal-links-troubleshooting-guide

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having issues getting Universal Linking to work.

You can probably find the issue using the Universal Linking Validator, here: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-linking-validator/guide/

There is also a guide that goes through other potential issues, such as testing issues, here: https://support.branch.io/support/solutions/articles/6000153326-ios-universal-links-troubleshooting-guide